# Закрытие формы JFrame

Tags: java

Создана форма JFrame на неё помещены две кнопки. При попытке добавить Textfield, он не отображается. Как это можно исправить? Пробовал создавать JPanel и в ней непосредственно создать его, но все равно ничего не получается.

Comment: после добавления вызовите у контейнера (компонента, у которого вызываете `add(..)`) `revalidate()` и `repaint()`

Comment: Спасибо) Скажите, а можно  как сделать, чтобы команда, которая написанная на Java взаимодействовала с базой данных MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставь после добавления всех компонентов setVisible(true)